# Unresolved reference 'ObjectId' Unresolved reference 'name1'

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

```py
@app.route('/editadm/<id>', methods= ['POST', 'GET'])
def editadm(id):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return redirect(url_for('admindash'))

    adminlog.update_many({"_id": ObjectId(id)},
                {"$set": {
                        name1: request.form.get('fullname'),
                        email1: request.form.get('addemail'),
                        phone: request.form.get('phone'),
                        job1: request.form.get('jobtitle'),
                        password: request.form.get('password'),
                }
        })
```

Comment: You should import `ObjectId` from the used library. As well as , Avoid  use of  `id` as a parameter name , it is a builtin function name of Python.